# Insert soft \newpage before sections

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

Normally, sections encourage LaTeX to `\pagebreak` so that if e.g. a section is close to the end of a page, it will get pushed onto the next page. I am happy with this behavior, except for one point: `\pagebreak` can potentially leave a lot of awkward spacing between the paragraphs on the previous page. Therefore, I would prefer to `\newpage` instead of `\pagebreak` if the section is going to have any break at all.

Note that:

- I do NOT want to `\newpage` unconditionally, but only if the `\section` would have had a break anyway.
- I am NOT attempting to alter the amount of text which must appear under a section in order for it to be considered "ok" with respect to page breaks (as asked in previous questions here).

Of course, I could do this manually by just adding `\newpage` in front of the offending sections. However, this is undesirable because I can only apply to the absolute final text (otherwise the sections may move), and is generally brittle. If there is a way to do this automatically so I can "fire and forget", then I would greatly prefer that.

I am using titlesec in case that makes a difference. I have made no other modifications to how sections are defined.

Comment: do you not just want `\raggedbottom` ?

Comment: `\vfil\section[title]{title\vadjust{\vfilneg}}`